# delphi accessing 200GB in images from a 32bit exe

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, delphi

On a windows server 2019, I have many directories under a main images directory, each with about 100 images.

A 32-bit executable currently relies on disk-caching for serving the images. The current load on the exe is  about 100 images per second. It's coming to the point where It seems disk-caching only slows the threads - each calling for a different image.

My initial thought is to have a 64-bit exe load everything in-mem (about 200GB RAM). The RAM on the server is sufficient.  Once loaded in the 64-bit exe - either find a way to share the memory between the 32-bit and the 64 bit exe's, or use TIdTCPServer   on the 63 bit and TIdTCPClient on the 32-bit, calling each time for the image.

Also, my initial thought of the shared-mem is the limit of the 32-bit EXE (unless there is a way) to access the shared-mem from the 64 bit.

Only other way I see possible is preloading MSSQL-server 2019 with the images in a memory-table - which would guarantee performance, reliability and lower the development/testing time on the TidTCP svr/cli.

The main idea is is to have a good reliable solution with the lowest headache for dev/test/lifecycle support.

Any thoughts with applicable code are welcomed
TIA

Comment: Have you considered using TransmitFile? Which is available from Winsock or IIS.  SQL Server would be expensive overkill.  Are you running with the LARGEADDRESSAWARE switch on your executable to get the full 4GB of usable memory?

Comment: Just FYI, Indy's `IOHandler` has a `WriteFile()` method that uses `TransmitFile()` internally if it is available and the `AEnableTransferFile` parameter is set to True (it is False by default).

Comment: @David B.  The 32bit has 1GB for images.  The IIS will only cache cache after a first load per image, but not available as preloaded, and still caching is not guarateed. 

Your SQL answer points me its a possible direction as it automatically takes care of any possible inserts/updates/deletes of images. 

1. is there a way to create a regular table to be also fully memory cached? if so its a great direction!

2. If 1 is not possible, how would I do a select-into a new memory table without the need to create then select into it?     I would create an index after the creation.

Thanks

Comment: @Remy.   
1. Do you have a sample code in mind? - say the onExecute on the 64-bit would receive an Id parameter from the 32bit and the original id and its image would simply be returned?  

1. Would there not be any transfer/handshake issues between TIdcpClient in 32bit and TIdTcpServer being 64bit ?

If your idea is workable, it would save looping through multiple SQL records due to its row-size limit.
Thanks

Comment: "is there a way to create a regular table to be also fully memory cached?" no but there's no need.  SQL Server will use all available memory for caching.  That option used to exist but was removed because it's unnecessary and dangerous.

Comment: @zaaaibon 1) no. 2) no.

Comment: @David. Would you recommend fixed size rows or as varbinary  without the 8K row limit? unsure if SQL would cache it the same way.
Looks like this is my direction.. I'd rathe have an overkill than insufficient or problematic. reliability always wins for lifecycle.

Comment: @Remy - is there a way to override the datasnap 16K limit on a returned TStream data? if so - everything will work out well without the need for TIdTCP coding.

Comment: SQL Server caches pages, not rows.  And the _only_ datatype you should use for large files is varbinary(max).  But stepping back, why not store the files on a really fast disk. A 1TB NVMe is trivially cheap compared to everything else you're considering.

Comment: Wish I could, unfortunately, the VPS server is standard SSD only without any NVMe options.  Also, more standard RAM would be a cheaper option than NVMe.

Comment: Have you considered putting your server disks into RAID configuration.

Comment: @SilverWarior  How would that guarantee 100% caching in-memory on over 200GB of data?

Comment: @zaaaibon That would not guarantee any in memory caching but instead speeding up disk access. I know you are thinking that since you have enough RAM on server right now caching all those images in RAM might be the best solution. And it might be today. But what about tomorrow or next month? Will the number of images stay the same or will it grow? If it is the later it could mean that someday in the future you end up in position when you would need more RAM that can be installed on your server. So all your work designing memory caching system would be just wasted time. ...

Comment: ... If you really need just a quick solution for speeding up access to those images today it might be better to just install RAM drive on your server and then let your program accessing all those images from RAM drive instead of regular drive. Then someday in the future when you upgrade your server with better disk drive capability you can revert back to accessing all those images from disk drive and you don't have to worry about total size of images since disk drives capacities are way higher than RAM capacities. ...

Comment: ... And no increasing RAM capacity would not cheaper than increasing disk drive capacity. or increasing the number of physical disks in order to arrange them in RAID configuration so that data is being read or written from more than one disk at a time and thus increasing disk access speeds.

Comment: @SilverWarior - Ram drive was the chosen for the interim period and for several architecture reasons. Well done. trying to give your comment as the selected answer.

Comment: @zaaaibon You can't mark a comment as an answer. Also while my comment provided you with possible workaround it doesn't really answer your question. As for your idea of loading all of the images into memory with 64 but application and then sending them to your application using network connection. You probably would not get any performance benefits but instead have even worse performance that you do now. ...

Comment: ... If you really want to go with direction of loading all of those images into a memory with your application then I suggest you turn your existing 32 bit application into 64 bit architecture entirely. I know this is easier said than done but it is most reliable way to do this.

Comment: @SilverWarior the RAM drive works perfect. Porting to 64bit is an option for the next version but from the start was already ruled-out for current release.